# How can I create new objects and add them to the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I've made a ball fall towards the ground. On `OnCollisionEnter2D` I've added the `print("ball hit ground");` to the event.

But what If I wanted a continuously rain of balls, destroying the one that hit the ground and generating a new one? I don't want it to be the same, as I over time want to add intensity to the rain of balls.

I got this on my ball script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collisionInfo) 
{
    GameObject newBall = Instantiate(Ball) as GameObject;

    print ("collision!");
    Destroy(this);
}
```

However, this will hang the whole Unity as it will create a ball at the same position as the current ball, forcing it to collide at once and generating ALOT of balls :D

What I want to happen is when a ball hits the ground, it should be destroyed and create a new one to fall. The destroy function as is, does nothing... shouldnt it delete the ball?

Answer (score 2):

The instantiate function can take three parameters; Game object to spawn, location, and rotation.

You can try something along the lines of

> Instantiate(ball, new Vector3(~put your own x,y,z in here~), Quaternion.identity);

This will create the ball at whatever position you put in the vector3. If you only do Instantiate with the game object and no other paremeters it will be created at the point of the object the script is on. Quaternion.identity is just the default rotation.

As for the delete function you can try

> DestroyObject(this.gameObject);

that will destroy the game object in the word.

Test those out and get back to me if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate allows you to set the spawn position of the object. Take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Since you're using 2d I imagine it'd take a Vector2 (not sure, never tried instantiate with a 2d game), along with a rotation (if you intend to have it rotated at a different angle).